# Taxonomy widget - select maximum level depth

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I want to make a taxonomy field widget that allows me to select the maximum level depth of the taxonomy vocabulary. This widget should be used in node forms and the value (selected term) should be saved in the node object.

What is the best (Drupal) way to approach this?

I don't want to use hierarchal select.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what your problem is. Don't you know how to create a widget, or is there something specific in the widget you are creating that is giving you trouble?

Comment: I have a taxonomy vocabulary with 3 levels/depths. In my node form I want to add a widget which allows the user to only select a term our of the first 2 levels of my vocabulary. (so the third level should can't be chosen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Content Taxonomy](https://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) is what you're looking for. It extends the default select list widget and adds a maximum level depth.

Answer (score 1):

For me not works any module to remove unnecesary taxonomy depths, but I can fix it with my own code like this:

function _remove_sub_services(&$form, &$form_state) {

```
foreach ($form['profile_fields']['field_select_the_service'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'] as $index => $value){

    if(strstr($value, '--')){
        unset($form['profile_fields']['field_select_the_services'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'][$index]);
    }
}


return $form;
```

}

// I call this code inside a hook_form_alter

Answer (score 0):

There is a new module called Client-side hierarchical (https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) that does a good UI and solves it.